# Laravel 5.1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I get this error when I try to access delayTime method. I can't see what I am doing wrong. I have the routes setup like this:

```
Route::post('quiz', [ 'as' => 'quiz', 'uses' => 'QuizController@create' ]);
Route::get('quiz/token/{quizByToken}', [ 'as' => 'quiz.token', 'uses' => 'QuizController@getQuizByToken' ]);
Route::get('quiz/code/{quizByCode}', [ 'as' => 'quiz.code', 'uses' => 'QuizController@getQuizByCode' ]);
Route::get('quiz/id/{quiz}/players', [ 'as' => 'quiz.players', 'uses' => 'QuizController@getQuizPlayers' ]);
Route::get('quiz/token/{quizByToken}/players/highscore', [ 'as' => 'quizzes.player.highscore', 'uses' =>    'PlayerController@highscore' ]);
Route::put('quiz/nextQuestion/{quizByToken}', [ 'as' => 'quizzes.nextQuestion', 'uses' => 'QuizController@nextQuestion' ]);
Route::get('quiz/poll/{quiz}', [ 'as' => 'quizzes.poll', 'uses' => 'QuizController@currentQuestion' ]);
Route::put('quiz/poll/token/{quizByToken}/delay-current/{delayTime}', [ 'as' => 'quizzes.delayTime', 'uses' => 'QuizController@delayTime' ]);
```

Error message:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 750
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 659
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
```

Comment: Can you show the error.

Comment: it is what it says in the title this is the short version: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 750
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 659
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139

Comment: Check your form if the method is a post or put.

Comment: it is a put method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the following route:

```php
Route::put(
    'quiz/poll/token/{quizByToken}/delay-current/{delayTime}',
    [ 'as' => 'quizzes.delayTime', 'uses' => 'QuizController@delayTime'
]);
```

Which means when you submit the form, you've to pass a hidden input field named `_token` with value `put` in it, for example:

```html
<form method='POST'>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <!-- Other Fields -->
</form>
```

I'm sure you missed it. You may check [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing) for more information on this topic.

Comment: Actually it is just an api, so I don't have any forms, I am just getting json data

Comment: Then pass `_method='put'` with your `json` payload.

Comment: it was actually me passing the parameter as an array instead of just as a string